# Does ExtrinsicBaseWeight apply even when we return 0 weight from extrinsic?

Tags: extrinsic, weight, fee, feeless

If we return `Weight::zero()` for an extrinsic that returns `DispatchResultWithPostInfo`, does that mean that we discard extrinsic base weight which is included for every transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Lets start with where we execute a block from the `executive` pallet, more specifically [`execute_extrinsics_with_bookkeeping`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/5d346643ca0d1b6d9ddcfb2d01e490858ce4cb0e/substrate/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L509). Then, we are going to `apply_extrinsic` where we [`get the dispatch info`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/5d346643ca0d1b6d9ddcfb2d01e490858ce4cb0e/substrate/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L587) of a particular extrinsic [(ref)](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/dispatch/trait.GetDispatchInfo.html#tymethod.get_dispatch_info) (run `cargo expand` on your pallet to find the implementation).

Followed in the next line we will [`apply`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/5d346643ca0d1b6d9ddcfb2d01e490858ce4cb0e/substrate/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L588) the extrinsic which (assuming it is a signed tx) [calls the `pre_dispatch`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/372929fa256f5839047bb5d569ad523cb4b15094/substrate/primitives/runtime/src/generic/checked_extrinsic.rs#L75) implementation of the `SignedExtensions` of your runtime (you can find them configured [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/372929fa256f5839047bb5d569ad523cb4b15094/substrate/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L303-L312)). As for the `check_weight` `SignedExtension` implementation it will call `do_pre_dispatch` which calls [`check_block_weight`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/372929fa256f5839047bb5d569ad523cb4b15094/substrate/frame/system/src/extensions/check_weight.rs#L101C1-L101C1) -> [`calculate_consumed_weight`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/372929fa256f5839047bb5d569ad523cb4b15094/substrate/frame/system/src/extensions/check_weight.rs#L67). Here you will see that the [`base_extrinsic` weight is added to the dispatch info](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/372929fa256f5839047bb5d569ad523cb4b15094/substrate/frame/system/src/extensions/check_weight.rs#L133) mentioned above.

Comment: So that's a yes to ExtrinsicBaseWeight being unconditionally being added even though my extrinisic returns 0 weight consumed?

Comment: Yep, since the base weight is the effort done by FRAME, not by your code.